# Git clone --no-checkout again

Tags: git, git-clone

I don't want to waste space on my machine and I only want to see the history of repository (for each branch). That's why, I did a:

```
    git clone --no-checkout
```

After I did this, somebody pushed something. I have to do something to be again with the history updated, but I don't know what. Of course, I can use git checkout & git pull, but I don't need the files, I need only the .git folder to be updated. I tried with git fetch, but it seems the history is not updated.

Comment: What is the output of git fetch?

Answer (score 12):

Use `--bare` option for `git clone`

**Update**:

after the cloning is completed make sure that the section `remote.origin` in the configuration (see `config` file in the repo) contains `fetch` key with an appropriate. The section should look like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = <upstream repo remote address>
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Then you may update the repo from time to time by issuing `git fetch` inside the repo.

Comment: Ok, so I used: `git clone --bare repo.git`. How can I update the bare-repo with the latest changes?

Comment: Hmm, as usually, `git fetch` inside the repo.

Comment: I would suggest to _manually_ set `core.bare` to `false` _after_ the bare repo was cloned. In this case you may use `git new-workdir` to temporarily instantiate a working dir for a required commit/branch when e.g. you need to view some files in a text editor. `git-new-workdir` is a unix-specific shell script in git contribs.

Comment: I also did a `git fetch` inside the repo, and after that, I run `git log`. However, the last commit doesn't appear in the log.

Comment: Please provide the content of `config` file for the repo, as well as `git fetch` output. I've just checked the recipe in several bare repos and it works indeed. You also may run `gitk --all` to visualize the changes graph.

Comment: Config file: `[core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = false
 symlinks = false
 ignorecase = true
 hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
 url = ...`       Fetch output: `Fetching origin
remote: Counting objects: 4, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), done.
From .....
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD`

Comment: Ahha, add `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` to the `[remote "origin"]` section and re-run `git fetch`. Now you'll get all the project branches (as remote branches) with proper reference list. I'll update the answer now